# Windows Service using .net core BackgroundService, how to gracefully stop?

Tags: c#, windows-services, .net-core-3.1

I'm developing a windows service using .Net Core 3.1

Lots of online resource suggesting me to use `BackgroundService` for it. Problem is I cannot get the service to be stopped gracefully, by just overriding `ExecuteAsync` method.

The codes setup for testing is very simple:

```cs
public class MyService: BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Service started at {DateTimeOffset.Now}");
        await DoLongRunningWork(stoppingToken);
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service is being stopped...");
        await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        Console.WriteLine("Service stopped at {DateTimeOffset.Now}");
    }

    private static async Task DoLongRunningWork(CancellationToken token)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm working...");
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t... doing work ...");
            await Task.Delay(1000, token);
        }

        // THE BELOW LINE IS NEVER REACHED. i.e The line "Cancel requested? True" is never logged out...
        Console.WriteLine($"Cancel requested? {token.IsCancellationRequested}");
    }
}
```

And the `Main` method

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting My Service...");
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<MyService>();
        })
        .Build()
        .Run();
}
```

One thing I can do is implementing my own `Stop` method and calling it in my override `StopAsync`. But I'm curious why this simple setup didn't work as expected.

I have read the [BackgroundService.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/3.1/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs) source code, it looks like it should work the way I expected (i.e. this line `Cancel requested? True` should be logged out but it didn't...

I have tried both running it as a console app and stopping it using `Ctrl+C`, as well as installed it as Windows Service and using `service.msc` to control it. Same behaviour (i.e. no gracefully shutdown...)

Any helps are much appreciated!

Comment: `DoLongRunningWork` and `TriggerExtraction` are same thing?

Comment: You need to restructure some of your service and should accept a DI parameter of `IHostApplicationLifetime` and hook into the stopping related events

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 the `stoppingToken` received in `ExecuteAsync` is triggered by `IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping`

Comment: @Artur eh... Kinda sorta. If you want graceful shutdown you need to link into it yourself. I have an answer to post with an example but need to clean it up

Comment: Please post a minimal repro.

Comment: @Artur spot on... Copied and pasted and forgot to update the method's names. I've fixed that.

Comment: `Task.Delay` should throw a `TaskCanceledException`, which you can catch.

Comment: I did notice `TaskCanceledException` got thrown sometimes, but not all the times, during my test. Doing gracefully shutdown in `OnStopAsync` would be better I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot about this for such a long time. And when I come back to it, I found out the issue... It was just a confusion

This particular line

```cs
await Task.Delay(1000, token);
```

will throw `TaskCancelledException` hence the loop will be exited the method will stop... @Jeremy Lakeman did comment about this but I didn't think it through at that time I guessed...

I'll just need to be careful with using `await Task.Delay(..., token)` with a cancellation token...

So, I created a simple extension

```cs
    public static async Task SafeDelay(this Task source)
    {
        try
        {
            await source;
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            // I don't want a throw on TaskCanceledException...
        }
    }
```

```cs
    private static async Task DoLongRunningWork(CancellationToken token)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm working...");
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t... doing work ...");
            
            // I simply want the loop to keep running, I don't want an absurd stop...
            await Task.Delay(1000, token).SafeDelay();
        }

        // This line is now reached...
        Console.WriteLine($"Cancel requested? {token.IsCancellationRequested}");
    }
```

Comment: I was just having the same issues as you and your answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue while following the official examples, and catching the `TaskCanceledException` did the trick, here's how my code looks now:

```cs
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Started");

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(60000, stoppingToken);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        _logger.LogInformation("Stopped");
    }
}
```

I'm now getting the "Stopped" log :)